# How to define separate color palettes per trace in R plotly plots?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to define two vectors of colors and apply them to two plotly traces.

```
col2 <- c("#b72b7f", "#2ba5b7", "#3e8236", "#f87b60", "#000000")
col1 <- c("#e65353", "#62e653", "#53a4e6", "#53e6da", "#e6b053")

iris %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = 0.3, color = ~Species, colors = col1) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = 0.6, color = ~Species, colors = col2)
```

However, it seems that plotly use only the colors in `col1` to color both of the traces.
What can I do to achieve the desired result?

[image: Image showing two lines of dots. They both use the same groups of colors.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As both traces share the same legend, looks like it will be necessary to make two distinct groups to have two colors groups :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

col1 <- c("#b72b7f", "#2ba5b7", "#3e8236", "#f87b60", "#000000")
col2 <- c("#e65353", "#62e653", "#53a4e6", "#53e6da", "#e6b053")

col1 <- col1[1:length(unique(iris$Species))]
col2 <- col2[1:length(unique(iris$Species))]

col <- c(col1,col2)

iris %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = 0.3, color = ~paste("1 -", Species), colors = col) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = 0.6, color = ~paste("2 -", Species), colors = col)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Waldi! This logic seem at least to apply to plots with two discrete color palettes. And, what if the second trace was trying to use continuous color (fx by mapping color to Petal.Length), instead of discrete? If you have any idea, i'd be grateful, thanks! :-)

Comment: @Bastian, glad I could help! For continous scale, if color arg values are positive you could use a color gradient specifying negative and positive values, and set trace 2 color values to negative